Error on VSCode when I manually deleted the files on Git server
Firstly I created a Git repos on my azure devops server and I tried to push a testing project to my Git server in VSCode.
It's fine when I do it at the first time.
And then because the uploaded project is a testing project, and I just deleted all the files and branch in the Git server and then re-create a new main branch.
However, when I try to open another new project in VSCode and do the same push process, it showed many different errors on the process.
It's fine when I just type the command [commit on "main"]
but it shows "Can't push refs to remote. Try running "Pull" first to integrate your changes" error when I tried to push.
Then if I tried to Pull, it will show another error "Git: There is no tracking information for the current branch"
How can I solve it? since I'm newbie to Git and VSCode
I tried to create a totally new project and also empty the Git server but it still shows the same error. Is it anything store in locally?

Does this answer your question? Make an existing Git branch track a remote branch?. As general advice, search the error message on SO (or the internet in general). It's not a VSCode issue, it's an error message from git that you can resolve on the command line, for example.

No, it doesnt work. honestly I already searched similar issue in Google or stackoverflow and tried to type different suggested command but still not solved so I just asked here

When you deleted and created the new main branch did you make it the default branch as well? Is this also a problem if you create a fresh repository? If it works with a new repo, then you might want to go through the repo's settings regarding main and applying them in your non-working repo.

The "main" brand should be the default brand and its the only one brand now in the repo, and honestly it's totally empty, actually I also already delete the whole folder of the original project as well, so I also not understand the local git info should be deleted as well? I totally not understand why the server git is empty and the new project folder is totally new but it still has errors......and what do you meaning of non-work repo?

main should be the default branch but have you checked the settings that it really is? Why do you write "brand"? Is that something else? non-working just means not working. Well does it work if you create a new repo and test with that? What are you using? GitLab or GitHub? Tags for that might also help to find people that can help you.

Sorry that "brand" is meaning "branch", its just a typo mistake.  I checked that the "main" branch is default one and the only one, I'm using azure devops, the repo is created by someone that I dont have the right to create a new one but I have full permission for the current one

@Daniel, you can confirm the remote info, branch, and rebase your local branch with the remote branch to make sure it's tracking with correct remote branch, please check the details below, thanks.


Can't push refs to remote. Try running "Pull" first to integrate your changes

This error typically occurs when your local branch and your remote branch are not at the same point before your changes. There could have new changes on your remote branch.

Git: There is no tracking information for the current branch

This error means your local branch isn’t connected to a corresponding branch on the remote server.
To resolve the error, you can

Close current folder, and open folder, find target project.



Go to Terminal -> go to git bash, type git remote -v to confirm the remote info.


If it doesn't have correct value showed, use git remote add origin <remote repo url> to fix.

Type git pull --rebase origin main to rebase your local branch with the remote branch, it will report conflict -> click the file on the top left, resolve the conflict, merge -> click Continue to complete.



It will fix your local code and remote code, then your local code is tracking correctly with remote,your Next change from local can push to remote sever successfully.
